# Can I selectively disable Spring Data repositories for testing?

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, spring-data

I'm writing a module-level integration test for a system using Spring Integration. I need the integration plan up and running but at this level am still using `MockMvc` and a mocked repository interface to ensure that I have all of my mappings, conversions, and message routing correct.

Right now, my module-level `Enable` configuration is meta-annotated with `@EnableMongoRepositories`, and the Spring test runner aborts because it doesn't have a live `mongoTemplate` to create the repositories from; the mock repository doesn't prevent the attempt to create real ones.

I know that I can conditionalize the inclusion of `@EnableMongoRepositories`, but is there simpler way to tell Spring Data not to create repository proxies if I'm already supplying mocks for them?

Answer (score 0):

Basaically if I understand correctly you have two kinds of set up for your MongoDB repositories, `mock` and `live`. So you want to run integration tests and control the repository that is being used. I would suggest using "Spring Profiles".

1. create an simple interface say `MongodbCofig`
2. crate two configuration classes for `mock` and `live`. Make sure these classes implement `MongodbConfig`. Set the profiles (`@Profiles`) in both the classes.
3. Later activate the required profile before running the tests

For detailed understanding of profiles you can refer [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: Profiles aren't what I'm looking for, since that's the hand-conditional I am trying to avoid.